# if / else in wordpress to pull a specific image

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I had some trouble with facebook pulling the wrong images from Wordpress links added to the FB news feed. I was able to correct it with the "if" snippet of code below. I added the "else" statement to provide for a fall-back image in case the user hasn't added a featured image to the linked WP post, but it doesn't seem to be working. Obviously I'm no php coder... any help?

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail())
 {
 $fb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
}

else {
 $fb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src ("http://MY-IMAGE-URL"), 'full');
}

?>
```

I also tried the code below in the else statement, but to avail

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( 732, $size, $icon )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in $size and $icon?

Comment: See the WP Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src  - it just chooses the image size to display or replaces the image with an icon.

Comment: I know what those parameters do. The question is: what were they when your wp_get_attachment_image_src failed?

Answer (score 1):

The function wp_get_attachment_image_src is used to get the URL (src) for an image attachment.
However, you cannot directly pass on an URL like you do as it works based on an attachment ID.

In your else statement, replace the line with the following in order to work with a default image :

```
$fb_image = "http://MY-IMAGE-URL";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when I edit the code as suggested I get the following error message from FB's debugger: Object at URL 'http://*******' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 's' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'."

Comment: Maybe I should use 'wp_get_attachment_image_src( 732, $size, $icon )' where 732 is the image id... when I do, I don't get the error, but thats not pulling the image.